# Adding to object after RenderBox HitTest

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a Positioned widget to a relative location after doing a hit test. The path goes as follows `Listener -> ListView -> SizedBox -> Container`.

I have tried to access variables within the returned path, but documentation is limited on how to do this.

```
    Listener listener = new Listener(
        onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
                      print('${event.position}');
            final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
                          final Offset localOffset =
                  box.globalToLocal(event.position);
                 var res = BoxHitTestResult();
                 box.hitTest(res, position:localOffset);
                 for(var r in res.path)
                 {
                   print(r);
                 }

        },
        child: Container()
);
```

```
RenderConstrainedBox#fffda relayoutBoundary=up27 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderRepaintBoundary#3afc3 relayoutBoundary=up26 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderIndexedSemantics#57986 relayoutBoundary=up25 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderSliverList#46e30 relayoutBoundary=up24 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPointerListener#b70ac relayoutBoundary=up19 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#8224c relayoutBoundary=up18 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPointerListener#62c4e relayoutBoundary=up17 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
_RenderScrollSemantics#fc217 relayoutBoundary=up16 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderRepaintBoundary#be170 relayoutBoundary=up15 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderCustomPaint#385db relayoutBoundary=up14 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderRepaintBoundary#3d0ab relayoutBoundary=up13 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderRepaintBoundary#a3e3b relayoutBoundary=up12 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderCustomPaint#83c0b relayoutBoundary=up11 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderRepaintBoundary#c3ec5 relayoutBoundary=up10 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPadding#0cbae relayoutBoundary=up9 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderDecoratedBox#760d1 relayoutBoundary=up8 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderFlex#41bef relayoutBoundary=up7 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#939e4 relayoutBoundary=up6 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
_RenderInkFeatures#a1c5e relayoutBoundary=up5 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPhysicalModel#19c78 relayoutBoundary=up4 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPointerListener#e553e relayoutBoundary=up3 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#dbe00 relayoutBoundary=up2 dart_sdk.js:19110:15
RenderPointerListener#0ce7e relayoutBoundary=up1
```

I expect to either be able to access and change the widget directly, or call an event inside of the widget in question, convert the supplied position to a position relative to that container, then add a positioned widget using relative coordinates.

Comment: what is `RenderBox box` in your case? are you sure you are using the right `context` when calling `context.findRenderObject()`?

Comment: Renderbox is only being used to do the hittest. I'm using the context of the whole page.I saw some using GlobalKey, but I'm not too sure how to utilize that with RenderBox to get the underlying widget. I am using a listener for pointer up events. The goal is to allow users to drag pins into content areas and the pin stays positioned exactly where they place it. Items are constantly being placed in the listview and I am trying to find the item of the listview where they drop the pin and then position it using the local coordinates of the container they dropped it on.

Comment: `RenderPointerListener#d9851 relayoutBoundary=up1`

I have my entire page wrapped in a listener.

Comment: ok, so it seems it is a valid `RenderBox` and your `for` loop shows valid `BoxHitTestEntry` (or `SliverHitTestEntry`) objects - what is the problem then?

Comment: Yes, I can see the entry for the item I am trying to add to, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this as they are not standard widgets. Is there a way to setup an event and convert the global coordinates to local for that specific container?

Comment: I have all of the cells for my listview inside of a map, so if I could somehow get the index (of my map) for the object that is hit, I could then easily replace it with an updated object. Not sure how to get the index though.

For serialization and scrolling purposes, it's important that I use to coordinates of the item within the listview, vs the global coordinates.

Comment: Could you keep an array of GlobalKey (one for each cell in the ListView) then loop over all keys and get its RenderBox (key.currentContext.findRenderObject()) and do a test to see if the point is in that render box? Then you know the index (from the array), and hence the widget that is the cell in your ListView and can manipulate it as required?
Assuming I correctly followed what you want to do...

Comment: How do I get the global key from the renderbox?

Comment: You need to iterate over them and do the hit test then given the index, you know the widget.

Comment: The listview perpetually grows and could contain many items. Still fine tuning on how many items need to be kept in memory, but I was hoping for a more performant approach. Is there not a way to gain access to the widget or find the global key of a hit object? It would be great if I could somehow dispatch an event to the widget from the Renderbox.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to attach a global key to a widget then wrap it in meta data providing the key as the data. Meta data seems to be the main way to communicate from the widget layer to the rendering engine and back.

```
MetaData( 
          metaData: widget.key,  
          child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
              ),
            ));
```

then, the meta data object can be accessed from the hit test to get the global key attached.

```
    Listener listener = new Listener(
        onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
          print('${event.position}');
          final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
          final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(event.position);
          print(box);
          var res = BoxHitTestResult();
          box.hitTest(res, position: localOffset);
          for (var r in res.path) {
            if (r.target is RenderMetaData) {
              var target = r.target as RenderMetaData;
              print(target.metaData);
            }
          }
        });
```

Now that we've found the global key from the rendering pipeline, we can easily search a map or list containing our keys to find the actual widget object and update as needed.